# functionFactory with an array template in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a hacky question of JavaScript.

For instance, we have a function as below:

```
var f1 = function(a,b)
{
    return a + b;
};
```

and now, I want this (or another) function generated by a factory function with a template described in an array, like this:

```
var fCode = [a, b, a+b];

var functionFactory = function(fCode)
{
     //........
     return f;
};

var f1 = functionFactory(fCode);
```

I understand that `functionFactory` is *consequently* a closure form, and my question is not that point.

I've tried object wrapper etc., but so far have not been able to find a clean implementation.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: When you say a template defined in an array, what exactly do you mean? The above code doesn't make sense, unless of course those are strings in the array.

Comment: oops, I thought the relation between both codes is so obvious, and have not expected there's a person who don't see that.

Comment: Well... you can sit here and berate the very people you are asking for help from, or you can try and explain what you really want.

Comment: I'm sorry I had encountered so many unproductive people here. Your answer did help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see to achieve *what I think* you are asking for is use the built in [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor.

You can create a new function by passing in parameter names and a function body like so:

```
var f1 = new Function("a", "b", "return a+b;");

f1(2,2); // 4
```

If you combine that with the built in [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method you can use an array as a sort of "template"

```
var template = ["a", "b", "return a+b;"];

var f1 = Function.apply(undefined, template);

f1(2,2); // 4
```

The first argument to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is what is bound to the `this` pointer when invoking that function. If you leave it undefined it will be the global object.

Comment: I tried to implement referring your answer, and the code amazingly works! Appreciated @Josh .

Comment: PS. For future references, the first code in your answer has `Error: The function constructor is a form of eval` (strict mode). The second one works as intended though.